# secretKeyOrPrivateKey must required error

Tags: nestjs, nestjs-passport, nestjs-jwt

[image]

I have given value of secretKeyOrPrivateKey value but same error again and again.
Please use this link for ref : https://docs.nestjs.com/security/authentication

Comment: Please post code not screenshots

Comment: https://docs.nestjs.com/security/authentication       follow this link  code and try with JWT example

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include your code and errors as **text** rather than as a screenshot. On stack overflow images should not be used for textual content, see [*Discourage screenshots of code and/or errors*](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/307500) and [*Why not upload images of code on SO when asking a question*](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557) for why. For instructions on formatting see *[How do I format my code blocks?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/22186)*. A [mcve] showing what you have tried that did not work would maximize your chances of getting help. See [ask].